# How to generate csv file by reading non standard property file

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, awk, sed

I have the sample file which is in not having standard format and need to generate CSV file with the following conditions, i am trying to figure out the solution past few days for this

```
 ab.db.contact-points=10.135.64.46,10.135.2.6,10.135.8.4
ab.db.port=9042
ab.token.uri=10.135.83.42,10.135.83.41
ab.db.port=9042#9042
ab.token.uri=10.135.83.42
deeplyiourl=https://deeply-internal-npe.example.com/testing/deep/v1/events/
TEST.URL=http://testing.unix.great20000.org:8115/CYBER/SOURCE
ABCDSURL=https://testing-tposs.data.dx-pk1.cf.example.com:443/saveResume/updateDecision?decisionXML={decisionXML}
simple.abcd02.uri=https://abcd02.pro.api.great.example.com/v1/author/testing?grant_type=abcd_credentials
abcd02.defo2-url=tcp://10.158.150.25:7222,tcp://10.158.150.99:72
findingdata.sentry.url=http://create.test.data.com:8555/FirstData/Payment
tstign.endpoint=http://create.test.ext.example.com:6002/ECL1/GatewayV3Proxy/ChargeSale
basic.endpoint=http://Validating/author/testing/v4/internal/test
TEST.URL=http://tesing.great.com
```

**Conditions:**

1. Consider only URL’s and Host name , IP address like endpoints with .com or .org or an IP should be considered.
2. Remove http:// and Https://
3. URL’s ending with .com or .org

   - remove anything after .com or .org
   - if there is port info in the URL use that port info

I have tried the below script but not getting the expected output

```
grep -P  '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' FASOfflineReviewAction.properties|grep '^[^#]'|awk '{split($0,a,"#"); print a[1]}'|awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed '/.com\|.org\|10.\|17./!d'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'|awk '/http:\/\//  {split($1,a,":");if (a[3] == "") print 80; else print a[3]}
       /https:\/\// {split($1,a,":");if (a[3] == "") print 443; else print a[3]}
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"}
       /host/       {h=$2}
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|sed 's/com.*/com/'|sed 's/org.*/org/'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'|sed '/^[0-9]*$/d'|awk -F, '$1 != $2' |sed -E 's_^https?://__'
```

Desired output

```
hostname      port
10.135.64.46  9042
10.135.2.6    9042
10.135.8.4    9042
10.135.83.42  9042
10.135.83.41  9042
10.135.83.42  9042
deeply-internal-npe.example.com 443
testing.unix.great20000.org 8115
testing-tposs.data.dx-pk1.cf.example.com 443
10.158.150.25   7222
10.158.150.99  72
create.test.data.com 8555
create.test.ext.example.com 6002
tesing.great.com 80
```

Comment: Is `#9042` a comment? Where does second `10.135.83.42` (line 5) get its port?

Comment: This might help as a first step in cleaning up: `grep -Po '(?<==).*' file | sed -En 's|(.*//[^/]*).*|\1|; s/#.*//; /http/{/\.(org|com)/p;d};p'`

Comment: @Cyrus No that port is not commented, it is separation of the port number and yes there are ip address but there are no port numbers at that we need consider default port as 9042 if there is ip address

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU grep and sed):

```
grep -Eio '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(:[0-9]{1,4})?|https?://[^/]*\.(com|org)(:[0-9]{1,4})?' file |
sed -E '1{x;s/^/hostname port/p;x};s#^https?://##I;/:/!s/$/:9042/;y/:/ /'
```

The solution is split into two parts:

- Extract the IP's and/or URL's using grep
- Add header and add/split ports using sed